# What is good practice to load data in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have two kinds of information:

- my messages
- messages to me

I can do one AJAX request in Angular to get all types of messages, approximately 2000+ notes. Then filter by `ng-repeat`.

But there are a lot of messages. Will it break the page and use a lot of resources? If yes, can I load data separated by click.
What is good practice to load data on page in Angular JS?

Comment: What backend do you have? If you can paginate at the backend database that would be perform a lot better than trying to bring all 2000+ rows to the client and then paginating on the client side

Answer (score 0):

You should load data using `ng-repeat` but don't load all 2000 records, It may cause performance issue while rendering DOM. I believe you should use pagination on those records for that use [**Paginate**](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) library

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview)

Comment: this paging will done on client end. not on server side..do you want server side paging?

Comment: Yes, can I use this library for load limited data from server with pagination. Because what reason use client pagination, if I get 2000 rows

Comment: yes this library will handle those 2000 rows.. and provide pagination for it..only you need to specify its setting

Comment: I need one example with Ajax rquest for two paginations in one page. From example I dont understand what does mean `on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)"` from where do I get value `newPageNumber`?